# How to check End of Life dates for SAP installation running on Solaris 11.1?

Tags: sap

I've been trying to work out SAP's end of life dates for a client's installation.

I've referred to PAM, however it seems like PAM doesn't provide the granularity that we need.

For instance, in PAM, there is an entry providing end of life info for our DB (listed as Oracle 11.2) and our Solaris (listed as Solaris 11).

However, the dates provided within PAM are for the latest minor version within the release. Hence, the dates indicated are for Oracle 11.2.0.4 and Solaris 11.2.

However our client is using Oracle 11.2.0.3 on Solaris 11.1.

For Oracle, I've managed to find SAP Note 1431799 that provides a breakdown on end of support dates for each minor version.

For Solaris however I couldn't seem to find such a thing. Not sure if I've been searching on the wrong keywords or anything, but does anyone else happen to have a similar problem before and managed to find the solution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed at the vendor (which with a valid support contract is not an issue)

Answer (score 0):

For Solaris End of Support you can check [this](http://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/lifetime-support-hardware-301321.pdf) pdf from Oracle

In general standard support for Solaris 10 is till January 2018

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response Romeo. Actually what we are after is the support from SAP.

IE: the patches and software corrections that SAP would provide for an instance running on X.XX version of the operation system with Y.YY version of the database.